# Terminal on VSCode is not grabbing the right python or ipython

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, conda, zsh

If I'm using a regular Terminal with zsh, I can start any conda environment and the python or ipython commands open the "right" version (on a particular conda env it is Python 3.7.7.).
[image]

But if I'm on a Terminal under VSCode, I always get a different version, as if it was not assuming the conda environment, although it the prompt shows me the correct conda env.
[image]
Any idea on what might be the problem here?

Comment: Is VSCode using the same zsh terminal?  I'm not sure if that would change your path.  I couldn't access aliases until I passed in the `shellArgs` flag `-l`.

Comment: related (duplicates?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/60836646/11107541 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72432622/11107541

Comment: This is not duplicated, this is a different issue than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving here the answer as I just found it is a known bug.

```
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5764
```

This happens for non-Windows machine and if the selected interpreter is a conda environment and "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" is not set. Solution is to set "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false.

Answer (score 1):

In .vscode/settings.json, you can put the python version required :

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

Comment: this is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code, its internal terminal is to integrate the terminal from the system, and it defaults to use the python environment selected in the lower left corner of VS Code when it was created. Therefore, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will Automatically enter the selected python environment, and for the selected conda environment, it will automatically activate it:

[image]

Also, please try to reload VS Code.

Reference: [Conda environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments).