# Different python versions when checking with terminal and command prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, version

In VScode, the result given from `"python --version"` on terminal is different than the version that I am in according to the command prompt. The terminal says that I'm in 2.7.16 when I should be in **3.11.2** according to the command prompt.

I tried to do `"python3 --version"` but that gave me version 3.7.7. I'm confused as to why they are different. I have a macbook.

I also tried:

```
python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'
```

Comment: This isn't so much a Python question as just how your PATH and shell are setup. Clearly you have multiple Python installations (quite common and not itself a problem) and different ones are being referenced in different contexts. So what's your question?

Comment: this question has been asked so many times https://stackoverflow.com/q/60836646/11107541 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72432622/11107541 https://stackoverflow.com/q/66670568/11107541

Comment: VS code (and in fact most good editors) let the user select which version of the language (in this case Python) that they want to use...

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to select a specific environment, use the **Python: Select Interpreter** command from the **Command Palette** (**Ctrl+Shift+P**).

[image]

The **Python: Select Interpreter** command displays a list of available global environments, conda environments, and virtual environments.

Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) about python environment for more details.